# web2py: custom forms are not being submitted

Tags: python, crud, web2py

i was working with custom forms in web2py and faced 2 problems

- 1) errors are not catched and displayed
- 2) form is not submitted :

after a validation/verfication i got those values:

```
form.accepts(request.vars, session) => False
form.errors => <Storage ()>
```

now what i have :

**controller**:

```
def new():
    form=crud.create(db.i2l_letter)
    print form.errors
    if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
        response.flash='Bitte warten'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash='Bitte fuellen sie das Formular richtig aus'
    else:
        pass
    return dict(form=form)
```

**view**:

```
{{if form.errors:}}
  Your submitted form contains the following errors:
  <ul>
  {{=form.errors.date_format}}
  {{for fieldname in form.errors:}}
    <li>{{=fieldname}} error: {{=form.errors[fieldname]}}</li>
  {{pass}}
  </ul>
  {{form.errors.clear()}}
{{pass}}
{{=form.custom.begin}}

<table>
<tr>
<td>{{=form.custom.label.date_format}}</td>
<td>{{=form.custom.label.myref}}</td>
<td>{{=form.custom.label.yourref}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{=form.custom.widget.date_format}}</td>
<td>{{=form.custom.widget.myref}}</td>
<td>{{=form.custom.widget.yourref}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>{{=form.custom.submit}}</div>
{{=form.custom.end}}
{{pass}}
```

so what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: why is not working with CRUD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have web2py 2.0+ try to replace your controller code with this:

```
def new():
    form=SQLFORM(db.i2l_letter)
    print form.errors
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash='Bitte warten'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash='Bitte fuellen sie das Formular richtig aus'

    return dict(form=form)
```

Comment: I dont know, I will try to debug it. 

But you know that crud is deprecated? it will work but it is better to use SQLFORM.

Comment: ah i didnt know that! although i was thinking that `sqlform` is the deprecated and its better to use crud read, create, update ... thanks!

Comment: Crud isn't officially deprecated, but most of what it does can now be handled via `SQLFORM.process()` and `SQLFORM.grid()`. Crud still has some unique functionality but isn't receiving much further development attention. Unless you really need Crud, it is probably better to stick with `SQLFORM`.

Comment: @BenIshak, I got this same error when I called `SQLFORM.accepts` conditionally only when `request_method == 'POST'`. So-generated form that never passed `.accepts` check on `request_method == 'GET'` was missing the hidden `__formname` input field. HTH,

Answer (score 1):

`crud.create()` handles the form processing automatically, so you should not call `form.accepts()` after it. Please read the [book section on Crud](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#CRUD).